# Azure notifications, registering devices server side. Notifications working for FCM but not APNS

Tags: ios, azure, notifications

I was following this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-push-notification-registration-management

So I wrote some test send code looks like:

```
  void TestSend(bool ios)
  {
     var AzureName = "myhubname";
     var AzureHub = new ServiceBusConnectionStringBuilder("Endpoint=sb://secret+sauce").ToString();

     var tags = new List<string>();
     tags.Add("doopy");

     try
     {
        var svcs = new ServiceBusConnectionStringBuilder(AzureHub).ToString();
        var hub = NotificationHubClient.CreateClientFromConnectionString(svcs, AzureName);

        // what is this?
        // var channel = await PushNotificationChannelManager.CreatePushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync();

        var installation = new Installation(); // control tag registration

        // FCM - works
        installation.Platform = NotificationPlatform.Fcm;
        installation.PushChannel = "put my fcm token here";
        installation.InstallationId = "see comment..."; // from the device via this call: myNotificationHub.Register(FCMToken, new List<string>().ToArray()).RegistrationId;

        if (ios) 
        {  // silently fails
           installation.Platform = NotificationPlatform.Apns;
           installation.InstallationId = "some guid I made up";
           installation.PushChannel = "see comment"; // device token with <> and spaces removed from call mySBNotificationHub.RegisterNativeAsync(deviceToken...
        }

        installation.Tags = tags;
        hub.CreateOrUpdateInstallationAsync(installation).Wait();

        JObject data = MakeNotification("notificationId", "I got your tags doopy!");
        var payload = PlatformPayload(ios, data);

        Console.WriteLine("Send...");
        if (ios)
           hub.SendAppleNativeNotificationAsync(payload, tags).Wait();
        else
           hub.SendFcmNativeNotificationAsync(payload, tags).Wait();
        Console.WriteLine("Message SENT!");
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
        Console.WriteLine("rats! " + ex.Message);
     }
  }
```

I don't even use the mystery PushNotificationChannelManager from the docs and FCM works. That class seems to only exist in UWP or something.

It seems that APNS requires both an installation ID and a channel, but all I have is a device Id. Anyone know where to get these values for iOS?

Comment: MobileServiceClient has a field InstallationId. Might be useful. Unfortunately, MobileServiceClient constructor requires a "mobile app uri" (string). Which mobile app uri? No idea.

Answer (score 0):

So I have found a solution.

Take the iOS device token, remove spaces and angle brackets and use that for PushChannel. Create your own InstallationId (Guid.NewGuid().ToString(); and save it somewhere) or just use the device token for both fields.